# Python2.7: Can I set the step length for the forward-difference approximation of the Jacobian in ODE solvers?

Tags: python-2.7, precision, ode, differential-equations, odeint

I have a system of coupled ordinary differential equations. The independent variable is time t.

In order to evaluate some of the derivative functions, I need to employ root finding, solving other ODEs and more. It is only feasible (from a computational cost perspective) to evaluate these functions with a certain precision. Thus, during each time step, I am left with some numerical noise.

I try to solve this system of ODEs with *scipy.integrate.odeint* or *scipy.integrate.solve_ivp* (using the 'LSODA' method since the problem is stiff and the other solvers for stiff problems fail). However, it seems as if the solver has trouble calculating the Jacobian (which I let the solver approximate by finite differences) due to the numerical noise. I had a similar problem when using scipy.optimize.fsolve to calculate roots and I fixed this by setting *epsfcn* (see below) to a higher value.

I wonder whether I can do something similar for an ODE solver in python. It seems that *odeint* and *solve_ivp* do not have such an optional parameter but maybe there is a way around this?

Any help is appreciated!

(From the scipy documentation of fsolve:
**epsfcn : float, optional**
*A suitable step length for the forward-difference approximation of the Jacobian (for fprime=None). If epsfcn is less than the machine precision, it is assumed that the relative errors in the functions are of the order of the machine precision.*)